# Blindly answering easy questions without considering whether the question satisfies MSE policy.

Tags: discussion, policy, homework

Here's the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3739977/782505) which motivated me to write this question.

Inspite of being clearly mentioned in the MSE's homework policy about [Avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/782505) this question was asked by the user. If the user is new, it is responsibility of other users to help them in knowing the policy of this site for asking questions.

But, instead of this, the question was simply answered without asking the OP for their attempt or what more they know about the context (may be just because the question was simple). The answer providers also include some of the highly reputed users of this site.

As quoted in the [FAQ thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/114)

> It's much better to give a hint, so that the asker may find the right direction.

This statement was completely ignored and there was flow of answers given by the users one-by-one. I thought this is a matter of concern so I wrote this question to draw attention of other users in order to prevent MSE being an homework service site.

Comment: [I have faced a similar problem, but slightly worse](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31972/same-question-format-but-one-question-gets-a-good-response-while-the-other-get)

Comment: I don't have the rep to see it but I think people voted to close it as a dupe

Comment: This has been talked about many times here. The best thing to do is vote to close the question and downvote it as soon as possible. I find that calling users out for answering generally only puts them on the defensive; they have no interest in recognising what they’re doing wrong. If it’s particularly bad or done repeatedly, then it’s worth downvoting the answer and/or calling the answerer out. Also, leave a comment under the question addressing the problem.

Comment: I always suggest that users judge OP by comments(that is, gauge the level/interest of the OP using comments) before answering the question, and this is usually my policy. The OP in fact responded (in Croatian : I love their accent) and said (briefly) : I tried it myself, failed and so asked the question. So yeah, people should've engaged with him but didn't, maybe because the question did have a trick, was too tempting(the usual). There was somebody who downvoted all the answers , though, probably to push the point across.

Comment: I largely disagree @gen-zreadytoperish. The answerers are the key to solving this problem. An asker may be on a throw-away account, but the asker has some skin in this game. I often downvote an answer to such a question *from an experienced user who should know better*.

Comment: The first 2 answers to the question do not completely solve it. They provide a partial solution to the question, giving the questioner the starting point they asked for. So it is not the case that the policy was completely ignored.

Comment: @user400188, also read the question asking policy. `Avoid "no-clue" questions`. However, only @peter.petrov has given the answer in expected format. But, the way in which the question was asked (may be for homework) which is not obeying MSE policy should also be considered by the answer provider before answering.

Comment: The policy for math SE is listed here. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question/1804#1804. It is not actually against the rules.

Comment: @user400188, check out the one which I've linked in this question above.

Comment: I read that link before my first comment and I have reread it. It is advice on how to ask a good question on the site, adhering to this advice is good practice, but it is not required.

Comment: Some users are just reputation hungry, and there's no reward for supplying helpful comments. This is also quite unfortunate because often times there are sufficiently helpful comments which don't really get the recognition they deserve, while there are tons of answers with up-votes which shouldn't have any.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг, it's my fault for not voting to close it as a duplicate. I wasn't sure whether or not I should vote for a lack of context or for being a duplicate. I avoid discussions in languages other than English, but I' d seen the previous question by the OP and realized he isn't fluent in English, so I tried to advise him in Croatian assuming he would understand me. I can't tell if the language he replied in is Croatian, Serbian or Bosnian by that comment because it's too short.

Comment: I don't object to anyone downvoting as they wish, and I think that's often a good way to handle cases where users have differing opinions about what's an acceptable question or answer. Just let the votes and downvotes handle it. But I have to say, despite the lack of context in the question OP linked to, I learned something both from reading the question and from reading the answer given by Yves Daoust. I would not want to remove this content from the site.

Comment: @Croissant  Look at the positives : you went out of your way to address this user, and I appreciate that. Look, mistakes, everyone makes. Admitting them, not many do that. If you're not sure which to vote for in case of a closure, then vote for missing context, since that covers most cases (while a duplicate works only if you have a duplicate candidate). I liked your contribution : to keep you going I'll give you a +1 on your best answer (which is worth it, anyway). Oh, and that is probably Croatian, from a fanatic of Slavic languages (and Tamil).

Comment: @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг, thank you for theadvice and support! As a student, it definitely enriches me. It's nice to both read your answers and hear you're a fanatic of Slavic languages!

Comment: @Croissant good luck and i hope you become a good contributor on the site!

Comment: It is odd that you claim to want to prevent Math SE from becoming a homework service site but yet posted an answer to [this pure problem-statement question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3743695). Do you admit that that question is pretty much as bad as the example you gave here?

Comment: @user21820: good catch! I have suffered from this problem and try to resist the temptation (sometimes by giving an approach in comments). Following rules (even those framed by oneself) requires a lot of discipline and courage and even with best intentions we sometimes falter.

Comment: @user21820, notice that in the answer I've directly concluded the final statement without any calculations involved unlike the answers which are given in the question mentioned in this meta question providing every detailed step. I'm not against all of the answer to that question. Few answers really intend to give hints but others didn't.

Comment: You're not answering my question. Do you admit that that **question** I linked to is pretty much as bad as the other question you gave in your meta post here? A question that is bad deserves to be removed, whether or not answerers give hints or full answers. Also, many cheaters ask for "hints" knowing that there are some users on this site who will give full answers.

Comment: -@user21820, 1. I didn't give full answer. 2. I can't remove question due to not enough reputation. If you want you can. 3. The request of revision was given by @Saad. 4. I gave answer after the two answers were already given. I agree the question was pretty bad but the methodology adopted to handle the question is indisputable.

Comment: @Doubtnut: Yes I know that you didn't give a full answer, and indeed giving a hint is better than a full answer. Thanks for that. You probably meant "disputable", but that is not true. You complain in this post that people answer no-clue questions with full answers. The only way to prevent that is to close the question. Whether you post a hint only does not prevent others from posting full answers. Do you think people who answer PSQs care if the question is closed after they have already gotten away with the rep? No; the only way is to delete the question. This is what the SE system causes.

Comment: @user21820, I mean "indisputable". Also, the users who provide complete answers thier answers are to be deleted. I am done with my job of giving hint. Secondly, I am a student and have many things to do other than MSE, so I'm not here for reputation heist. If you think so, you've accessed the moderation tools and can delete my answer (as well as the question). Others who provide complete solutions are to be blamed for that. I really didn't mind that you pointed out my question rather this is what keeps the site maintained. Also, let me know any question which I've answered violates MSE policy.

Comment: Ok I now understand your stand on this, and thank you for your support. Just in case you are not aware, it is impossible for non-moderators (even with high rep) to delete answers unless they have a negative score. This implies that often the only way to delete complete solutions to PSQs is to delete the question. That's what I meant by "what the SE system causes". Also, it seems to me that the moderators agree with deleting the question rather than answers (unless the answer itself has a serious problem). Anyway, thanks for responding!

Comment: There is also the issue that Stackexchange moderators are delete-happy for comments.  When I ask helpful comments like those suggested by the FAQ, they **very** often get deleted and "sent to chat" because "comments are not for discussion"

Answer (score 16):

This really should be a comment to an answer from a now deleted account, but I want to elaborate on a point, and also get a reality check from others. So an answer it is.

Quoting

> The truth is that 99% of math.stackexchange is just people repeating information they learned in some class or from reading a book or lecture notes. There is no actual difference between helping someone in algebraic topology or functional analysis and calc 1 or linear algebra besides ego. The gatekeeping of, "oh, is this question good enough for us to reply?" is nonsense. If it's below your standards, just ignore it.

The complaint seems to be that the bulk of janitorial work is directed at lower level questions (=sophomore or below) while advanced undergrad and graduate level homework questions in their opinion fall through the cracks.

Given that at least [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9292/11619) I wanted to give more advanced questions some slack, I took this a bit personally in the sense that the accusation somewhat fits my tendencies. I thought about this, and want to share.

> Yes, I have voted to put on hold at least ten times as many calculus / elementary-number-theory / combinatorics questions in comparison to higher level questions.

But this is not really such a heavy bias in my voting *policies*, nor those of the other CURED-activists.

- Sheer numbers. There are many more low quality questions in lower level tags. Simply because world wide there are more students at those levels.
- I'm on record for fighting duplicates with passion. The more advanced questions are much less likely to be duplicates. The number of questions at a particular level correlates with the number of people at that level in their studies, and this forms a triangle (or a pyramid) sitting on its low level base. The amount of mathematical knowledge, on the other hand, forms a tree-like structure, more like an inverted pyramid. These two factors imply that the duplication is disproportionately concentrated on the lower level tags. Given that I scan the close queue mostly for posts that PSQs as well as duplicates (particularly those likely to become fodder for FGITWs), this will make my "vote-to-close" stats look skewed towards lower level. My desire to "punish" FGITWs probably skews it further.
- If I run into a PSQ in stochastic math I will likely just click "Skip" simply because I lack the expertise to determine whether sufficient context has been given in the question. Likely many other follow similar (intellectually honest) policy, again with the net result that basic questions get more attention from the reviewers.
- But, I'm just a single reviewer. Judging from my observations the more systematic CURED-activists don't pay attention to the factors of the previous bullets. For them a PSQ is a PSQ irrespective of its level. Undoubtedly there are many other active reviewers all using their subjective criteria.

> So it is not surprising at all that the net effect is that lower level questions are more likely to be put on hold by the reviewers. On the other hand, seeing this as a bias favoring deeper stuff seems misguided, when statistical explanations exist.

Comment: Well i am suprised that you cared, their accuscation comes with no supporting data and from their profile, which is now gone, I dont see that they are active in higher level tags.

Comment: From what I see in the different geometry tag, PSQ gets closed most of the time. Indeed, the situation is even better since everything happens slowly: almost no users will answer those question 3 minutes after it's posted.

Comment: I really don't think this quote was the point of his answer. To me, the main point was that there's really not harm in answering "bad" questions.

Comment: Hard to tell for sure, @Cronus. If that was their point, then I simply disagree strongly.

Comment: Why do you disagree?

Comment: @Cronus That has been explained many times. Answering bad questions begets more bad questions. We already have too much of a reputation as a homework mill. Hitting those who want to answer bad homeworks questions is the only way to stop the deterioration.

Comment: Then there's also the rep game. Some users want to play by different rules, ruining it for the others. That's less serious of a problem, but cannot be ignored entirely.

Comment: I guess I'd agree with you if I thought "bad questions" were really bad. But I don't. I don't see the point in forcing people to write down their efforts, or write well, or whatever. To me this site should just be for asking questions, of whatever kind, and anyone should be welcome to use it. I just enjoy answering people's questions and am happy to have mine answered.

Comment: @Cronus But this site was created to become a well organized repository of knowledge. If only there were a way to resolve this. Your approach will (or has already), over time, lead to severe duplication of questions, and increases the entropy. The homework mill reputation has already turned off many of the best potential answerers. A compromise is necessary. Hence the PSQ policy **that nobody likes - not even those who seek to enforce it.** That's what compromises often look like.

Comment: A palatable alternative would be to not allow any homework questions- Good effort, bad effort, no effort all - not allowed. Physics.SE does that and they seem to have less quarrelling (though undoubtedly there is also a vocal group there who would want to abolish the restrictions).

Comment: I'm not against erasing duplicates, actually (although I do think a lot of people here mark things as duplicates *way* too quickly, without actually reading the question thoroughly, and often do it erroneously). But, regarding the other things, I don't see how it gets in the way of making this site a repository of knowledge.

Comment: The argument has been rehashed many times in meta already. Repeating it here, in whatever form my knee-jerk reactions would do it now, is not an efficient use of our time. Just check out the related threads in meta.

Answer (score 7):

The truth is that 99% of math.stackexchange is just people repeating information they learned in some class or from reading a book or lecture notes. There is no actual difference between helping someone in algebraic topology or functional analysis and calc 1 or linear algebra besides ego. The gatekeeping of, "oh, is this question good enough for us to reply?" is nonsense. If it's below your standards, just ignore it.

Comment: If the primary goal of Math SE were to provide one-on-one help to individual users, I would agree with you.  However, that is not the model on which the site runs.  Instead, the goal is to help users to get answers, primarily through *searching*.  Having large numbers of low-quality and duplicate questions clouds the search results and makes it that much harder to find what one is actually looking for.  Answering a particular no-context PSQ might help that one asker, but it may also go on to harm many *future* questioners.

Comment: [From Atwood's blog:](https://blog.codinghorror.com/what-does-stack-overflow-want-to-be-when-it-grows-up/)  "Passively searching and reading highly ranked Stack Overflow answers as they appear in web search results is arguably the primary goal of Stack Overflow. If Stack Overflow is working like it's supposed to, 98% of programmers should get all the answers they need from reading search result pages and wouldn't need to ask or answer a single question in their entire careers. This is a good thing! Great, even!"

Comment: @XanderHenderson I know what the theoretical model is, and I don't think it works in practice for math. Most users are not around long enough to be socialized into your utopia to use it correctly on your terms, like pro or semi-pro programmers. They just want to know what the MLE of their weird contrived stats problem is, or whether a particular set of vectors is linearly independent, or whatever.

Comment: @XanderHenderson If you want things to be closer to your utopia and you don't want to gate the ability to ask questions based on reputation, the next best solution is to allow users with a high enough rep to merge questions and answers ex post to prune the database and make it more searchable. Instead of playing these silly games with potential users of the site and closing their questions, just fix the problem ex post and merge all the redundant questions together.

Comment: I completely disagree with your statement "I know what the theoretical model is, and I don't think it works in practice for math. Most users are not around long enough to be socialized into your utopia to use it correctly on your terms, like pro or semi-pro programmers."  For a counter example, look at [physics.se].  They have a very strict "no homework" policy, and manage to maintain a good signal-to-noise ratio.

Comment: Regarding giving high XP users *more* power, let us be realistic: many of those users got their reputation by answering large numbers of poor questions.  They *currently* have the power to close questions as duplicates, but rarely do so.  What makes you think that they would bother to use *increased* powers?

Comment: That being said, your initial question was "why don't you just ignore low-quality questions?"  I gave you an answer:  low-quality question/answer pairs pollute the database and make the site harder for everyone else to use.  I think that experienced users who encourage such questions by answering them are a much larger problem than the transient newbies who ask poor questions, but closing such questions is one of the few tools we have.

Comment: @XanderHenderson The canon of math is extremely large and varied, and in many scenarios it is going to be hard to decide what questions are even duplicates. I am not saying those users would. I am saying it is an outlet for users like you to pursue what you think would improve the quality of the site.

Comment: I honestly cannot parse your intended meaning from that last comment.  What are you suggesting?

Comment: @XanderHenderson The people going around closing questions and posting the standard "welcome...learn to ask a question..." posts: redirect their effort towards consolidating accepted answers on similar questions into fewer, better entries. For example, instead of putting questions in a queue and cleaning questions as they come "in", put accepted answers in a queue and clean them as they go "out" relative to the existing database.

Comment: Okay... but until the SE overlords decide to implement this feature that you are suggesting, what should we do?  There is a real problem **now**, and only limited tools to deal with that problem.

Comment: @XanderHenderson  I regard this "model" as the fundamental problem in education.   Academia has been overrun by people who think the question is more important than the asker. When a freshman asks a question in Calc 1, the most likely result is a lecture on why the question should have been worded differently. By the time the TA is done babbling, the kid isn't interested in the answer any longer.  Yes, this is the SE model, but then, SE fired Monica, so screw 'em.  I'll do what I please.

Comment: @B.Goddard You are somehow conflating the classroom, where professors and TAs are *expected* to provide tailored, one-on-one interaction in order to teach individual students, with SE, where the goal is to build a database where askers can help themselves.  Regarding your last comment, if you are dissatisfied with the corporate overlords, you are always free to leave.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I conflate nothing.  I am asserting that I don't care what SE's stated goals are, because those goals are misguided.  In the case of the question cited by the OP, it wasn't even really a "I have no clue"  question, because he went to say what didn't work.  Some of us are better at picking up cue's than others and we can tell the difference between someone's who'd tried and gotten no where and someone who hasn't tried, whereas you can't.  Yet we get brow-beat by your type because you insist on dragging us down to your level.  I have less than zero tolerance for someone trying

Comment: @XanderHenderson how to talk.  I'll decide that.

Comment: @B.Goddard There are a lot of people on here who construct their identity by adhering to the "rules" and try to impose those made-up rules on other people, and then excel at the made up game they demand to play. I don't think you can get anywhere with such a person by arguing, because the answer will always be, "but the rules!", even when you've already affirmed that you don't care. I don't know why they went into math, they belong in law enforcement.

Comment: @Renard Alternative theory: the same people recognize the value of the rules they're enforcing and how it will prevent the site from becoming a big bin of crap.  I know your version appeals to all the armchair psychologists out there, but Occam's razor says this alternative theory is simpler, IMO.

Comment: @rschwieb And I think it is great that you have an opinion, and got the chance to share it with all of us.

Comment: @B.Goddard I think you're exaggerating the impact of pushback against questions that are initially bad, and ignoring the benefits of pressuring posters to improve their posts.  I think it would be worth your time to consider how, in many cases, appropriate criticism is *healthy*, both on this site and in the classroom.  One should not shield them from everything.

Comment: @Renard (Regarding the contents of the answer itself) I am sorry to see your opinion of math.se and its value is so low.  It is understandable then you don't have an impetus to worry about maintaining site quality.  From that perspective, I can see why you would write this.

Comment: @rschwieb Please refrain from trying to read my mind in the future, you are not good at it. We just measure site quality differently, and I think if you build a social system and people do not use it as you intend, you should blame yourself for the outcome, not rudely treat them like an inconvenience.

Comment: Renard, you apparently seem to want this site to be a Yahoo Answers lookalike. Citing the founder again. "StackExchange is a Wiki first".

Comment: @B.Goddard ". I am asserting that I don't care what SE's stated goals are, because those goals are misguided." That means that you are part of the problem rather than part of the solution.  We have too many users thinking they have the right to act as they please as it is. The policies Xander and others are defending were formed as compromises. It is not ideal to anyone, but that's how compromises often look like. Would you prefer a site were homework questions are simply forbidden?

Comment: The people fighting against "rules" are not unlike those who think that football is more fun without rules like off-side. After all they can score more goals that way. Ruining the game for those who want to play by a common set of rules. Or, if baseball is your game, then you are like a pitcher thinking "I'm more productive, if I can balk at will".

Comment: @Renard Now now, if it is awkward that what your post shouts loudly and someone can read it plainly, there's no need for deflection. If this is how you treat people who empathize with your viewpoint, then it seems you are no stranger to rude treatment at inconvenience.  As I said, if you're convinced that "99% of stackexchange is regurgitation for ego's sake" then we have different views of the site.

Comment: @rschwieb My last comment to you talked about how we have differences of opinion about site quality, and I don't think you should blame users if your site incents them to behave in ways you don't like. Your last comment to me was just a wordy version of "u mad bro?". Who, exactly, is deflecting here?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Those systems are well-designed to incentivize the behavior intended. This site is not. A bunch of people here want to blame the novice and first-time users and police them. OK, well I don't think that makes much sense, and will end with either a bunch of frustrated people or a bunch of math superusers in a bubble.

Comment: Renard, you have been here for only 3 months. Possibly the worst 3 months in site history given that pandemic measures have brought in students who would normally ask their teachers or class mates for help. You don't have the perspective.

Comment: FWIW I'm not blaming the novices. I am blaming the answerers who fall for the incentives. Initially (like 8-9 years ago) I wanted the higher level questions get treated differently. But they don't. The rules are the same for high scool trig and algebraic geometry.

Comment: And, for my money, there is no difference between a copy/pasted homework question and a copy/pasted textbook answer. If neither poster showed any effort (timing data is telling), then downvote it is.

Comment: @rschwieb Weird that the phrase "99% of stackexchange is regurgitation for ego's sake" appears precisely nowhere in the post I wrote. It's not even an honest paraphrase. Look, I won't be interacting with you further, but I hope things improve for you.

Comment: @Renard I thought that was a pretty accurate paraphrase of your answer, … just to provide the perspective of someone who wasn't participating in this discussion.

Comment: Here is what I think of answers on MSE. If any textbook even reached half the quality of most answers here, we would not need teachers at all. The content on MSE is of far more superior quality because of the actual reputation / ego of the answerer being at stake. In a typical textbook what is at stake is not the authors reputation, but just the publishers investment.

Comment: @MikePierce I wrote, "There is no actual difference between helping someone in algebraic topology or functional analysis and calc 1 or linear algebra besides ego" There is a huge difference between that and "99% of stackexchange is regurgitation for ego's sake". People are fine trashing posts on calculus or linear algebra, but I've seen plenty of posts about, whatever, the weak topology, the fundamental group, that ask for help without much "context".

Comment: @Renard (1) I disagree with your assertion that " People are fine trashing posts on calculus or linear algebra, but I've seen plenty of posts about, whatever, the weak topology, the fundamental group, that ask for help without much 'context'."  I have voted to close or delete a fair number of high-level PSQs.  However, this happens rarely, because...

Comment: ...(a) there are simply fewer people who study higher-level mathematics (*most* undergraduate students in the US have to take some college level mathematics, including calculus; only a small percentage of undergrads take advanced mathematics; even fewer go on to grad school), and (b) students studying higher-level mathematics are generally a little older, more mathematically mature, and likely to have had some experience writing mathematics; as such, they are more likely to pose their questions welll.

Comment: (2) Several people, including myself, understood your statements to mean "99% of stackexchange is regurgitation for ego's sake".  If one person misunderstands you, fine, they might not have been reading carefully.  If several people misunderstand you, it might be worth your time to rephrase your comment in order to ensure that you are not misunderstood.

Comment: @user762914 Good answer. I wish more people here thought like you.

Comment: Just jumping in as a recent university grad - the rules describe exactly what I look for when I ask questions. Being given answers that explain everything instead of giving hints or an explanation of a subtlety I missed is aggravating. Who actually benefits from questions or answers that don't provoke thought? Maybe I'm reading too much into it, but the dynamic of questions being answered without even trying to figure out whether askers attempted anything themselves seems a bit insulting to their intelligence.

Comment: @AlenaGusakov My answer advocated ignoring content you don't like, and you (among others) are making a bunch of assumptions about what I think. Everyone is not like you, many are at different stages of their math life and need different things, and policing other people's questions and answers is tedious and deeply illiberal. It assumes everyone is alike and learns alike. If you want to give/get hints, great, give/ask for hints. If you want to write up a complete answer, sure. If you hate something, well, just click away, there's plenty of math and Internet for everyone. That's my post.

Comment: @user762914 it's not about policing though, I think question askers genuinely benefit from people engaging with them. The point is just that *answerers* should take care to communicate with the askers to figure out where they are in terms of attempting the problem so they can actually give helpful, targeted answers. No, everyone is not like me and people are at different stages in their math life, I never argued the opposite. What other commenters have argued is that lots of unspecific, contextless questions make it harder to find the information you need, and I agree with that.

Comment: No matter what stage you are at in your math life, you benefit much more from communicating with others (i.e. spelling out what you've tried/what specifically you don't understand and having that addressed) than from simply stating "I don't understand this" and having walls of text in response. Like, pedagogically, back-and-forth communication *is* better than just passively reading text, and I think answerers should encourage that.

Comment: @AlenaGusakov I have many students, particularly non-English speakers and undergraduates for whom math might as well be a foreign language, who barely have an idea where to begin, and something is better than nothing. I am fine with back-and-forth communication and get annoyed at how often I get the "continue in chat" message when I'm conversing with someone. But that's all personal preference. Some people are very smart, the problems are boilerplate, and they just need to see the "trick" that sets the analysis up for success. Everyone is different.

Comment: @AlenaGusakov For the most part, I think the "context" discussion is really just about raising the cost of asking questions, not fostering engagement with posters. Many, many posts don't need context: the questions are not about deep, subtle proofs, they're families of questions that get asked of every math cohort and have a standard approach. And I doubt the people I've been arguing with are advocating for the kind of engagement you suggest; I would guess they want a crisp question and a crisp answer with a min of crosstalk (they'd say the answer should be updated to incorporate the chat).

Comment: @user762914 That's fair. I vaguely remember someone suggesting answerers chat with askers about their thought process in the comments before going straight for the answer, and that's what I view as engagement. Also something about how the current system doesn't really reward that. I just don't feel like scrolling all the way back up, it's a long thread. I didn't get the impression that anyone was advocating for stricter barriers to entry, just that people answering should help askers flesh out what they need first. But yeah, I guess the foreign language thing isn't something I considered.

Comment: @AlenaGusakov I appreciate your passion for doing math in community and wish I had more colleagues with the same enthusiasm.

Comment: @user762914 thanks :)

Answer (score -7):

Maybe an alternative opinion: answering such questions is fine, but if they aren't a useful question to future users of site, then they should also be downvoted and closed too, and eventually deleted. The answerer can do all of this. Then OP gets [whatever level of help the answerer has energy for](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13846/167197), and the post doesn't make it tougher to find useful questions on the site, and doesn't provide a bad example for future question-askers.

Of course actually giving such users help might attract more of them, making more work for the vigilant mods and [CURED-saders](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/cured), but I'm skeptical of the intensity of this effect. Like, I can't imagine naïve students looking for homework help find this site via word-of-mouth from peers who've gotten help asking homework questions here before; they probably just Google their exercise and find similar stuff already on MathSE. So, I mean, as long as these questions get removed, I don't think answering them will flood the site with folks asking homework questions, turning MathSE into homework-answering service.

Comment: `I don't think answering them will flood the site with folks asking homework questions` I'd argue that that is exactly what happens. As long PSQs are answered, people will make throwaway accounts to ask them.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber I mean, I haven't seen any evidence supporting your claim or mine. Do we have any? Does anyone want to start interviewing the students just asking for their homework to be done? Asking them how they found MathSE, are they repeat offenders, etc.

Comment: +1 I think you make some good points here. Word-of-mouth is not, in my experience, how these askers come to the site. In fact, when I do overhear some word-of-mouth about this site with my students, it's always very much negative. The net effect of our policy and its enforcement appears to be to convince students that we are openly hostile to anyone with undergrad-level knowledge or lower, which I'd accept from mathoverflow, but not from the "question and answer site for people studying math at any level".

Comment: My friend, who is an associate professor, finds this site hostile too when he asked his research level question. I dont think this is peculiar to lower level questions.@theo.

Comment: @TheoBendit [I created a question where you might like to share what you've heard](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32053/167197).

Comment: There is plenty of evidence supporting @AlexanderGruber's claim. I am sure that the moderators can easily dig up hundreds from user flags of PSQ sockpuppetry if they had nothing better to do. And that is just those that get caught. You also know that most cheaters will deny cheating, so what's the point of asking them?

Comment: @TheoBendit: In my opinion all that matters is that students who actually want to learn mathematics find Math SE a beneficial place to learn. I don't care how many mathematics majors who don't want to learn mathematics criticize Math SE. Also, there is an inherent sample bias in looking at students who come to Math SE to ask how to solve their homework, because most students who want to learn don't lazily copy-paste their question into google to find solutions! I came across Math SE by accident myself, as I wasn't looking for homework help.

Comment: @user21820 This isn't about the existence of sockpuppet shenanigans though. It's about how the rate of such bad questions being asked depends on them being answered or not. Like, will answering them actually increase the frequency that they get asked?  I say no, so long as the question is removed. If sockpuppetry is your concern, then answering the questions will actually help things because then these users won't have to make another account to ask the same bad question. ;)

Comment: I guess you're joking, but to be clear, it's not sockpuppetry that we don't want; it's the abuse of sockpuppetry to circumvent the closure or deletion of their earlier questions (which in some cases even results in a temporary ban). If we are firm enough to stamp out bad questions, Math SE will gain the reputation of not being a homework mill and people will stop coming here for a quick fix for their laziness.

Comment: @TheoBendit: By the way, slightly relevant to this is that I am in support of being very lenient towards new users as long as effort is shown, and this includes not insisting on LaTeX and nice formatting. To me, I would rather have a question with a picture of a handwritten significant attempt than a LaTeX-formatted question with no effort whatsoever.

Comment: @user21820 I'm mildly kidding; I don't think I'm as invested in this a you are. Lol about the reputation of the site though. Like, this site isn't *that* well-known. You think the lore of MathSE being a no-go for homework solutions will spread far and wide, passed down through generations of college students? They don't care as much as you do either.

Comment: You're right that it's hard to back either claim with data, as we (unfortunately) don't have any significant period of time when bad questions weren't answered for long enough to signal a culture change. I will say this however: almost everyone I've spoken to about math.SE in real life perceives it as a homework mill. That includes a lot of people, some classmates who use it that way, and some who just avoid it due to this reputation. I've also personally seen homework and takehome exam questions *that I've written* pop up here a number of times.

Comment: A site people expect to function as a homework mill attracts questions fitting for one. If we can change its perception, it will attract different content.

Comment: To stress a point, it maybe does not change much for the *first* question a person asks, but many a person will have more than one question to ask. Thus, if they get answers they will continue to post them. If they do not get answers they might stop or revise their approach.  There are persons that literally have a dozen of accounts to evade questions bans. The **only** remedy is not to answer.